# Parse cloud code check for key duplication

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I developed an iOS app using Parse. When user sign up, I want to check if his phone number exist. So I write the following Parse Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    var toSaveObjectId = request.object.get("objectId");
    console.log("UserName: ");
    console.log(request.object.get('username'));
    //if (typeof obj.foo != 'undefined')
    if (typeof toSaveObjectId != 'undefined') { //If toSavedObjectId is defined, then it will be an update. 
        console.log(toSaveObjectId);
        response.success(); //Just allow update to perform. Sadly, we never access here.

    }
    else { //If not an update, meaning an insertion
        var phoneNumer = request.object.get("additional"); //I use ParseUI so they use "additional" field for phone number. There is no problem with it.

        //Now check duplication
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.equalTo("additional", phoneNumer);
        query.count({ // If found 2 when signing up:Still do not allow. If found 2 when updating: Still allow.
            success: function(count) {
                if (count > 0) { //Found duplication
                //Duplication while signing up. Do not allow
                    response.error("Duplicated phone number") ;
                }
                else { //Object to sign up is equal to object found. Meaning updating. Allow updating
                    response.success();
                }
            },
            error: function() {
              response.error("Some error when checking user phone number before saving");
            }       
        });
    }
});
```

This method did execute when I sign up, and if I choose a non-existing phoneNumber, I could sign up. But then the user can not have any updates. I suspect that beforeSave is called everytime an update is performed, and it always returns error "Duplicated phone number".

I did try to avoid this by checking

```
var toSaveObjectId = request.object.get("objectId");
```

If toSaveObjectId is not defined, then it will be an update. So we should return success. However, the code is still not working and I still got "Duplicated phone number". So the problem is with the condition:

```
if (typeof toSaveObjectId != 'undefined')
```

My questions are:

1) How to fix the condition?

Now my log did work. I see this:

```
E2015-05-01T12:28:01.817Z]v21 before_save triggered for _User for user 1oDlr2aqi6:   

Input: {"original":{"additional":"+84913037492","createdAt":"2015-05-01T12:16:20.838Z","email":"daominht@gmail.com","objectId":"1oDlr2aqi6","sessionToken":"r:RJVZ5hlp7z5gRBtnuydWkuCA1","updatedAt":"2015-05-01T12:16:20.838Z","username":"abfadsfsd"},"update":{"point":220,"promoCode":"1oDlr2aqi6576","usedPromoCode":"7UjadcDdAi43"}} 

Result: Duplicated phone number 

I2015-05-01T12:28:01.848Z]UserName:  

I2015-05-01T12:28:01.849Z]abfadsfsd
```

In https://parse.com/apps/(project-name)/cloud_code/log

EDIT:
I change "if (typeof toSaveObjectId != 'undefined')" to

```
if (toSaveObjectId != null)
```

but not works neither. I just try console.log() for some request.object.get('column name'). It is so strange that only console.log(request.object.get("username")) will work correctly. If I want to print other column of request.object, I will always get this log: "No Message provided" in Cloud code.

Comment: `var toSaveObjectId = request.object.get("objectId");
    if (typeof toSaveObjectId != 'undefined') ` - this will always be defined; check for null instead?

Comment: This is what is got so far: 1) I changed to if (toSaveObjectId != null). Then I got "success/error was not called". Then I commented  out console.log(toSaveObjectId);, not I got "Duplicated phone number". So strange

Comment: I just try console.log() for some  request.object.get('column name'). It is so strange that only console.log(request.object.get("username")) will work correctly. If I want to print other column of request.object, I will always get this log: "No Message provided" in Cloud code. So I suspect THIS IS THE REASON. And the bug is from Parse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally this is my working code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    //console.log(request.object.isNew()); //You could also use this. request.object.isNew() return yes if the request try to insert new record rather than updating.

    if (request.object.id != null) { //If toSavedObjectId is defined, then it will be an update
        response.success(); //Just allow update to perform

    }
    else { //If not an update, meaning an insertion
        var phoneNumber = request.object.get("additional");
        if (phoneNumber == null || typeof phoneNumber == 'undefined') { //phoneNumber == null or undefined mean not signing up with phoneNumber. So let it sign up.
            response.success();
        }
        else {
            //Now check duplication
            var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            query.equalTo("additional", phoneNumber);
            query.count({ // If found 2 when signing up:Still do not allow. If found 2 when updating: Still allow.
                success: function(count) {
                    if (count > 0) { //Found duplication
                    //Duplication while signing up. Do not allow
                        response.error("Duplicated phone number") ;
                    }
                    else { //Object to sign up is equal to object found. Meaning updating. Allow updating
                        response.success();
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                  response.error("Some error when checking user phone number before saving");
                }       
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Some takeaway not:

1) For certain attribute of request.object, do not use .get("key"). For example: for objectId, don't use .get("objectId"). Use request.object.id instead.

2) If you console.log() some object for example console.log(request.object) You may got "Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object." when logging a newly created object". Someone please explain in more detail?

3) if you try to console.log() on some null/undefined variable, the next line of code will not be execute. So you may get "No return success/error".

4) You could use request.object.isNew() as another way to check if this request trying to create new object (return yes) or trying to update an existing one (return no).